# Convert String to ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, timestamp-with-timezone, datetime-parsing

I try for convert string to ZonedDateTime.
this is my code :

```
String startTime = "Wed Mar 21 2018 08:00:00 GMT 0330 (IRST)";
String endTime = "Fri Mar 23 2018 08:00:00 GMT 0430 (IRDT)";
ZonedDateTime startTimeDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(startTime);
ZonedDateTime endTimeDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(endTime);
```

and error :

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Wed Mar 21 2018 08:00:00 GMT 0330 (IRST)' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Comment: `ZonedDateTime.parse(String)` parses string in format like `2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]`. You'll need to define a `DateTimeFormatter` for you custom format and use `ZonedDateTime.parse(String, DateTimeFormatter)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the default version of the [parse method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-), it has the default formatter of `2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]`.

You need to pass a correct [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). To me the [RFC_1123_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME) seems the closest to your format, but it's not a match, so you will need to create your own.